Error: release: not found when trying to rollback existing helm release
I am currently running into an issue where when I try to rollback a helm release (that exists) I am getting an error saying the release cannot be found.
When I run helm rollback johndoe-anon-app 1, I keep getting the error Error: release: not found, but I expect to be able to rollback the release as normal.
When I try the command helm list I get the following output which contradicts the above error:
NAME                NAMESPACE                           REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART       APP VERSION
johndoe-anon-app    service-johndoe-anon-dev    12          2024-04-30 06:26:05.708824 +1000 AEST   deployed    app-1.12.0             

I have already run the command kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=service-johndoe-anon-dev so I don't think this is a namespace issue. Does anyone have recommendations for further avenues for troubleshooting?
